# Why does this function application generate a runtime error in purescript?

Tags: purescript

I have the following PureScript snippets; note `parseXMLFromString` is partially applied:

```
parseXMLFromString ∷ String → DOMParser → Effect Document
parseXMLFromString s d =
  parseFromString "application/xml" s d

parseNoteDoc :: DOMParser -> Effect Document
parseNoteDoc = parseXMLFromString TD.noteXml

note <- parseNoteDoc domParser
```

The following code is generated:

```
// Generated by purs version 0.12.4
"use strict";
var Effect_Console = require("../Effect.Console/index.js");
var Test_Data = require("../Test.Data/index.js");
var Web_DOM_DOMParser = require("../Web.DOM.DOMParser/index.js");
var parseNoteDoc = Web_DOM_DOMParser.parseXMLFromString(Test_Data.noteXml);
var main = function __do() {
    var v = Web_DOM_DOMParser.makeDOMParser();
    var v1 = parseNoteDoc(v)();
    return Effect_Console.log("TODO: You should add some tests.")();
};
module.exports = {
    parseNoteDoc: parseNoteDoc,
    main: main
};
```

The line `var v1 = parseNoteDoc(v)();` gives the error `TypeError: parseNoteDoc(...) is not a function`.

I'm not sure where the extra `()` is coming from on `parseNoteDoc` but that is the issue. When I manually remove the `()` in the generated source, it works works as expected.

**Update:** Added the code to reproduce this on [this branch](https://github.com/bbarker/purescript-dom-parser/tree/bad_function_call). After the usual formalities, `npm run testbrowser` and open `dist/index.html` in a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: your FFI code is incorrect, you need to add an extra `function()`.

---

**Longer explanation**:

The extra empty parens come from `Effect`.

This is how effectful computations are modeled in PureScript: an effectful computation is not a value, but a "promise" of a value that you can evaluate and get the value as a result. A "promise" of a value may be modeled as a function that returns a value, and this is exactly how it's modeled in PureScript.

For example, this:

```
a :: Effect Unit
```

is compiled to JavaScript as:

```
function a() { return {}; }
```

and similarly, this:

```
f :: String -> Effect Unit
```

is compiled to JavaScript as:

```
function f(s) { return function() { return {}; } }
```

So it takes a string as a parameter, and then returns `Effect Unit`, which is itself a parameterless function in JS.

In your [FFI module](https://github.com/bbarker/purescript-dom-parser/blob/14ab230e168a21a4713e9c93836888b4111b6901/src/Web/DOM/DOMParser.js#L8-L14), however, you are defining `parseFromString` as:

```
exports.parseFromString = function (documentType) {
  return function (sourceString) {
    return function (domParser) {
      return domParser.parseFromString(sourceString, documentType);
    };
  };
};
```

Which would be equivalent to `parseFromString :: String -> String -> DOMParser -> Document` - i.e. it takes three parameters, one by one, and returns a parsed document.

But on the PureScript side you're defining it as `parseFromString :: String -> String -> DOMParser -> Effect Document` - which means that it should take three parameters, one by one, and then return an `Effect Document` - which should be, as described above, a parameterless function. And it is exactly this extra parameterless call that fails when you try to evaluate that `Effect Unit`, which in reality is not an `Effect` at all, but a `Document`.

So, in order to fix your FFI, you just need to insert an extra parameterless function, which will model the returned `Effect`:

```
exports.parseFromString = function (documentType) {
  return function (sourceString) {
    return function (domParser) {
      return function() {
        return domParser.parseFromString(sourceString, documentType);
      }
    };
  };
};
```

(it is interesting to note that `makeDOMParser :: Effect DOMParser` is correctly modeled in your FFI module as a parameterless function)

---

**But there is a better way**

These pyramids of nested functions in JS do look quite ugly, you have to agree. So it's no surprise that there is an app for that - [`EffectFn1`, `runEffectFn1`, and friends](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-effect/2.0.1/docs/Effect.Uncurried#t:EffectFn1). These are wrappers that "translate" JavaScript-style functions (i.e. taking all parameters at once) into PureScript-style curried effectful functions (i.e. taking parameters one by one and returning effects).

You can declare your JS side as a normal JS function, then import it into PureScript as `EffectFnX`, and call it using `runEffectFnX` where needed:

```
// JavaScript:
exports.parseFromString = function (documentType, sourceString, domParser) {
  return domParser.parseFromString(sourceString, documentType);
};

-- PureScript:
foreign import parseFromString ∷ EffectFn3 String String DOMParser Document

parseHTMLFromString ∷ String → DOMParser → Effect Document
parseHTMLFromString s d =
  runEffectFn3 parseFromString "text/html" s d
```

---

P.S. People who purchased `EffectFn1` also liked [`Fn1` and friends](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-functions/4.0.0/docs/Data.Function.Uncurried#t:Fn1) - same thing, but for pure (non-effectful) functions.

Comment: Excellent explanation; on another repository I had not needed to add the extra `function()` for my tests to pass, interestingly, though I haven't dived into why that was the case. I fixed it up to meet this convention and it remained working, though, so all is well - and great to know about EffectFn* for next time!

Comment: This probably means that your tests don't actually test anything. For example, you may be obtaining the value of type `Effect a`, but never evaluating it to obtain an `a`, so the test doesn't crash and you think all is well.